# Save row data from editable datagrid jeasyui to database

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-easyui

I have a problem when i create a row editing datagrid jeasyui(not edatagrid), when i save the row, data does not enter to the database.

```
function updaterow(target){$("#dataGrid").datagrid("refreshRow",getRowIndex(target));

    　　var data={　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　
    　　　　　　　　"pos_name":row.pos_name,
    　　　　　　　　"pos_iis":row.pos_iis,
    　　　　　　　　"pos_cat":row.pos_cat,
                   "pos_sales":row.pos_sales

    　　　　　　};
    　　  var saveurl="module/emp-position/mod-update.php?&id="+row.id;
    　　　$.ajax({
    　　　　　　    type:"post",
    　　　　　　    url:saveurl,
    　　　　　　    data:data,
    　　　　　    success:function(result){
    　　　　　　　　　　     if(data.success){
    　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　      return data;
                                           $('#dataGrid').datagrid('reload');
    　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　     }
    　　　　　　　　　　    }
    　　   });}
```

I hope someone can help solve my problem

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. As we are unable to examine the AJAX details, we would need you to review this in your browser. Using the browser tools, look in the web developer section for Network. this should show all the HTTP Requests. Then test your update script and see what data is being sent to and from the script. Please edit your post and include these details. You will also want to check the Console to see if there are any alerts or errors.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue is related to the following bit of code.

```
success:function(result){
  if(data.success){
    return data;
    $('#dataGrid').datagrid('reload');
  }
}
```

There are two things incorrect here:

- The function is passed `result` yet you call `data`, this will be `undefined`
- You execute `return`, no other code will be processed, so your 'reload' call will not be executed.

Try the following:

```
success: function(result){
  if(result.success){
    $('#dataGrid').datagrid('reload');
  }
}
```

`success` callback usually does not require a return, but it should not if you choose to `return result`. The data is passed into the success callback using `result`, defined by you. So inside your function, you need to use `result` to access the returned data.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, but still can't, maybe my coding was wrong from the start. sorry, I'm still new to jeasyui. the data still doesn't want to enter the database. if you wish if you have an example of using the editable datagrid save to database, it might be shared for my learning material.